# \longdivision using [separators in work = false] generates a Missing number error

Tags: errors, latexit

I’ve spent a bit trying to debug this, but wanted to make sure it wasn’t a known bug before killing myself.

I’m trying to use the `\longdivision{}` command in a LaTeXit equation. It’s alone in the equation, and I have `\usepackage{longdivision}` in the header.

Used alone (`\longdivision{2345}{9999}`) all is well. When I add separators in work (`\longdivision[separators in work = false]{2345}{9999}`), I get an error `Missing number, treated as zero`. I’ve tried in standard and text modes.

I’ve also tried in an absolutely vanilla TeX document and get a similar error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longdivision}

\longdivision[separators in work = false]{14.1}{3}
\end{document}
```

gives

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/longdivision/longdivision.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def))
))
./Untitled.tex:4: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   s
l.4 ...vision[separators in work = false]{14.1}{3}
```

I'm not sure if I should contact the package author on something like this.

Comment: in texlive 2022 it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `longdivision.sty` prior to version 1.2.0 (released during the lifetime of TeX Live 2020) there is no separators in work` option.

Update your TeX system. Possibly downloading the most recent version of `longdivision` from CTAN might work, if you want to wait for upgrading.